# valueOf method for Graph

Tags: java, string, graph

Has anyone ever had to make a valueOf method to Graph (using Edges and Vertexes in different classes) of String that comes out of toString method? I have been struggling days with it, can't get it done. I just need a clue how to do this, don't need anyone to do this for me.

Comment: A good way to ask a question is to show us the code you're using, show us your expected output and also the output you're getting

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the `toString()` method of [AbstractGraph](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/blob/master/jgrapht-core/src/main/java/org/jgrapht/graph/AbstractGraph.java) from [jgrapht](http://jgrapht.org/) library for inspiration.